# Fetch data from another table to select in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-5.5

I got a problem when I try to fetch data from table to select.
here is my **Mahasiswa** model :

```
protected $fillable = ['nim','nama','alamat','jenis_kelamin','no_tlp','email','tempat','tanggal','link','id_jurusan'];
protected $table = 'mahasiswa';

public function jurusan(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Jurusan');
}
```

here is my MahasiswaController :

```
public function create()
{
    $data['data']= Mahasiswa::with('jurusan')->get();
    return view('Mahasiswa.mahasiswaInsert',$data);
}
```

and here is my blade view :

```
{{ Form::select('id_jurusan',['' => 'Pilih Jurusan']+$data ,1,['id' => 'jurusan', 'style' => 'display:inline-block','class' => 'blue-text']) }}
```

I just wanna get the data from table **jurusan** and fetch to the **select** ?? how to do that?? Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad grammar.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/08/25/populating-a-laravel-form-multiple-select-box-with-hasmany-relation-values/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model.

```
protected $table = 'mahasiswa';
protected $fillable = ['nim','nama','alamat','jenis_kelamin','no_tlp','email','tempat','tanggal','link','id_jurusan'];

public function jurusan(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Jurusan','id_jurusan','id');
}
```

And i think this enough your solutions for controller,

```
public function create()
{
    $data= Jurusan::get()->pluck('name','id');
    return view('Mahasiswa.mahasiswaInsert',compact('data'));
}
```